# Image on splash screen not showing

Tags: android, xml

I add my app logo on my splash screen but for some reason the image is not showing only if i run the app on a physical device or emulator, on the design preview is showing correct. Also i try to change the `visibility` to `visible` but again is not working.

**activity_splash.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_splash_scene"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="426dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.448"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.73" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="by george sepetadelis"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.99" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I don't know much about xml layout...

try to change

> app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo"

with:

> android:src="@drawable/app_logo"

Comment: Makes sense, since the Activity is Compat...Hum as i can see u are having trouble in the Layout preview, right?

Comment: Try do give CTRL + E and give a look at the Layout Inspector.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: I forgot to ask, are u still having the problem?